# Put php variable in shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode

I want to put the variable in the shortcode, but it is not working. What i have done wrong.

```
<?php $calendar = getCalendarTag();?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[ai1ec tag_name=".$calendar."]"]' ) ?>
```

Comment: Your shortcode is mssing quotes before the `.` and you also have an extra `]`. It should be `'[ai1ec tag_name="' . $calendar . '"]';`

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your code to:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ai1ec tag_name="' . $calendar . '"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this line of code if you store shortcode in a variable:

```
<?php
 $contact_popup_form = '[contact-form-7 id="91" title="Contact form"]';
 echo do_shortcode($contact_popup_form);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, no: in your example the question would be how to set id or title from a PHP variable.

Comment: Then simply store values in php variables. e.g. 

$title = 'Contact Form'; 
$id=91; 
echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="'.$id.'" title="'.$title.'"]');

Answer (score 0):

```
  $val= $options['c_form'];
  echo do_shortcode("$val");
```